# Multisite / Network - Stable?

Tags: multisite

I have about 15 individual WordPress sites running on my server and am looking at re-creating those sites under the multisite area to avoid having to update each install.

My question - I heard some remarks about a year ago that multisite wasn't quite "ready" or may still have some quirks.

I really need these rock solid, should I be concerned?

Answer (score 3):

The remarks were referring to non-technical people finding it harder to install and manage a network of sites, as opposed to a single WP installation.

With regards to stability, it's running on wordpress.com with millions of blogs and billions of pageviews, for crying out loud. :)

Answer (score 0):

No. WordPress Multisite will handle just fine with proper caching.